# ASP.net MVC 4 Error when trying to delete a record

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to delete a client record. The client contains an address and I guess I'm having issues with the order of deletion when it comes to their relationship.  Basically I want to delete a client and if they have an address, to delete that along with it.
This is the complete exception error message I get:

> **DbUpdateException was unhandled by user code**
>
> An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key
>   properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will
>   return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source
>   of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made
>   easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See
>   the InnerException for details.

**Models**

```
public class Address
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Street Address")]
    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Postal Code")]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string City {get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Province {get; set;}

    public virtual Clients client { get; set; }

}
public class Clients
{
    [Required]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [Display(Name = "Phone ")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual Address Address {get; set;}

    [Display(Name = "Email List")]
    public Boolean EmailList { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "E-mail")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Hair Type")]
    public string HairType { get; set; }        

   [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**Context Class**

```
public class VolumeV2Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<GiftCard> GiftCards { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Clients> Clients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Address> Address { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Inventory> Inventories { get; set; }  


    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Clients>()
            .HasOptional(j => j.Address)
            .WithOptionalDependent()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

       /* modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
            .HasRequired(j => j.client)
            .WithRequiredDependent()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true) ;                           
        */


        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

**Client Controller Delete Method**

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(long id)
    {
        //find the client
        Clients clients = db.Clients.Find(id);

        //find the address
        Address address = db.Address.Find(clients.Address.Id);

        //  set the reference to null?
        address.client = null;                       

        //remove the address foreign key?
         clients.Address = null;

        //Apply to db?
         db.Entry(address).CurrentValues.SetValues(address);
         db.Entry(clients).CurrentValues.SetValues(clients);

        db.Address.Remove(address);

        //remove the client
        db.Clients.Remove(clients);
        //exception error happens here 
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Is there something wrong with my order or deletion ? or am I just not doing something right? I just want to have the ability to remove clients with or without an address.

Comment: plz post the inner exception you are getting on delete operation

Comment: sorry. I posted it now

Comment: when you get the exception copy the inner exception message and post it here

Answer (score 0):

Remove the reference from an address to a client. Just keep your reference from a client to an address, that will do.